# Chaging dynamically Reference.cs of WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory, wcf-proxy

I am in the process of developing a WCF Service(WCFManager) which would send out request to other services and get response back. For this I developed a WCF service.

Trying to accomplish the following (Assuming that my service name is `WCFManager`)

What I did so far

1. Added a service reference of `Service X` to `WCFManager` which created a reference.cs and a WCF Client.
2. Using the WCF Client generated by adding service reference and sending the request to `Service X` by using the following code

   ```
   WCFManagerClient client = new WCFManagerClient();
   Response response = client.GetResponse(request);
   ```

What am I trying to accomplish

1. I want to add few config settings in a `App.Config` file of `Service X`, `Service Y`, `Service Z` which I did.
2. Reuse the same WCFManagerClient to send the request to `Service Y` or `Service Z` by reading the endpoint information from the config file. My assumption is that when I use the `WCFManagerClient` to send the request it uses the reference.cs created in the service reference of the WCFManager service.If my assumption is true can I change the reference.cs on the fly to include the `Service Y` binding information when I send the request to `Service Y` and same with the `Service Z`. This way I don't have to create a proxy for each Service.
3. Is it possible to reuse the same reference.cs file generated but include the binding information on the fly from config file.
   3.I have no control over the `Service Y` or `Service Z` but all I know is services Endpoint information and the method names and the schema of each service would be the same.

I am not sure if  this is possible in WCF if some one has gone through such design with WCF but any suggestions about my approach is apreciated.

Comment: You could add a service reference to both Service Y and Service Z (one reference per service), and use the appropriate reference as needed.  Alternatively, you could look at using `ChannelFactory` or `ChannelFactory<T>` to create a factory for each service, and then create channels as needed from the appropriate factory.

Comment: My whole point is not to add service reference for each service .I wan to add a single service reference and reuse it .

Comment: The only way that would work is if all the services you want to use have the same contract.  Then you could change the service URI and the binding as needed for each client.  If the services are different, then you will need to either do this via a service reference for each service, or programatically in the code via `ChannelFactory` or `ChannelFactory<T>`.

Comment: How about can we change the reference.cs on the fly with the same client ?

Comment: I don't think you can.  What you're trying to do can't be done - "Reuse the same WCFManagerClient to send the request to Service Y or Service Z by reading the endpoint information from the config file."  Once a client is created and opened, there is very little you can change regarding that client - binding is one of the things you definitely cannot change.

Comment: Option 3 might work for you - take a look at the overloads `WCFManagerClient()`.  I haven't used WCF with service references in a long time, but IIRC you can specify the binding and the endpoint in one of the overloads.  But you will have to create a new client everytime - you can't create a new client and then reuse it for another service.

Comment: Yes I am trying to implement the option 3 but i am unable to change few things when it loads the reference.cs. But when i manually change the reference.cs i am able to call service Y with service X client.So i have to find a way to change those values which matter on the fly before i send a request.